# How to install MBR with Maverick or Karmic

Tags: 10.10, bootloader

I have been using Ubuntu since 9.10. Now Maverick crashed and my MBR is wrecked. I have run `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=512 count=1` on advice from another Ubuntu user but now I can only install any Windows release and no Ubuntu. How do I completely erase the MBR and then  use an Ubuntu live CD or another HDD with Ubuntu on to install a Linux-only MBR please.

I am rather new at the technical side of Linux and have bandwidth shortage problems so I can't download large amounts of data. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=512 count=1` It just fill the MBR with zeroes (on /dev/sdb in this case ...). To install/reinstall MBR you should use grub-install.

Answer (score 1):

I have to admit I don't know exactly what you are asking, but if you want to reinstall the bootloader *grub* then you need to enter the following at a terminal (Applications->Accessories->Terminal):

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

This will install grub onto your [first] hard drive. You may also want to reload the list of operating systems that grub uses when you startup:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Both of these commands will prompt you for your password.

Answer (score 1):

Follow this detailed guide to reinstall GRUB 2:

[https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Reinstalling GRUB 2](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Reinstalling%20GRUB%202)

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer a GUI way then download [Grub Customizer Portable](http://portablelinuxapps.org/show/?d=Grub%20Customizer%202.1.DirIcon) then mark the applications ‘executable’ after download - Right click > Properties > Permissions > Check ‘allow executing as a programme’  then double-click and run and then click File -> install to MBR.
[image]